# How to export more than 1 animation to glTF

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I have 3 different animations that are parented to different objects, however when I export only 1 of the animations actually goes through.

Is this a blender export problem or a limit to glTF format?

Thank you!

Google drive link to .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LT1m-rgwz9xxFFpgSu3acho31GzYam9d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show a screenshot of your NLA editor.

Comment: Hey! Heres a screenshot of how I parented the animations: https://imgur.com/a/gl29n5z
Im not very familiar with the NLA editor but I included a screenshot of that too

Comment: Looks okay. You have the "Animation > Group by NLA Track" option on (the default)? If you reimport the glTF, which animation is the one that comes through?

Comment: Sorry, where do I find 'Animation > Group by NLA Track'? And I re:imported the glTF and the animation named "Rotation Anim" is always the only one that gets applied.

Comment: On the screen where you export. Why don't you upload the .blend.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but I have a video where I show usage of the NLA editor to export glTF animations:  https://youtu.be/pNA8ujgtogM?t=932

Comment: I added the link to my .blend file (Google Drive), really appreciate everyones help! :)

Comment: There are four animations in the exported .glb when I try it. You can check in the NLA editor after reimporting it, or in an online viewer like https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/.

Comment: Interesting, it seems by looking at the model viewer you linked that this isnt a glTF or Blender issue. It's a model viewer issue. Google Model viewer for example can only show one animation at a time. Do any of you know of a way to combine all the animations into one?

Comment: Easiest way is to turn off "Group by NLA Track".

Comment: Ah yes! Turning 'Group by NLA Track' worked! All the animations got combined into a global one. But just one more thought, is there a way to preserve the individual animations while still keeping the global one? So that they would play together but the individual animations could still be controlled via JavaScript later if needed.